# Google Group Setting API, shows error on updating group setting

Tags: .net, google-api, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

I am working on client interface which pushes and pulls information from [Google Group Setting API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/get_started) and google group api. This client interface is written in asp.net (vb.net). I have successfully created group, added members, removed members and changing role of members through Google Group API and Group Setting API.

Problem is with updating group setting, when I update group setting `whoCanPostMessage` to `ANYONE_CAN_POST`, api throws following error :

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError PermissionDenied: Cannot allow
>   external entities to post. [400] Errors [ Message[PermissionDenied:
>   Cannot allow external entities to post.] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid]
>   Domain[global] ]

The important point is that, I am getting this error only when I am changing group setting `whoCanPostMessage` to `ANYONE_CAN_POST`, all other options like "ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_POST", "ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_POST" and "ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST" are working fine.

I am not sure why I am getting above mentioned error on changing setting `whoCanPostMessage` to `ANYONE_CAN_POST` only.

Can anyone please assist me on this?

Comment: Experiencing the exact same issue.  I think there is some other settings that conflicts with making this public.

Comment: @Halsafar - have you fixed it ??

Comment: @Halsafar - Account i am using to access api has this limitation. Please check developer console.

Comment: I solved it, see the posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.

- Go to the admin console for your account (https://admin.google.com/).
- Click Apps -> Google Apps -> Groups For Business -> Advanced Settings
- Under "Members & email access"

  - Enable: "Group owners can allow members from outside this domain 
    Domain admins can always add members from outside this domain"
  - Enable: "Group owners can allow incoming email from outside this domain"

Wait a minute.

Now I can modify all the settings that I could not before including "whoCanPostMessage".

Hope this helps.